# 30m/10m/1m resolution DEM for microtopography research

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, lidar, resolution, topography

I am conducting research in a region of Illinois that does not have a LiDAR dataset. I am looking to develop a fine scale habitat species distribution model; however, the coarse data available (30m/10m) does not capture the microtopography of my study area. What recourse do I have in this situation? Can the 10m DEM be re-sampled perhaps to more accurately reflect the actual landscape? Should field surveys be employed in addition to re-sampling?

Comment: Are you aware the [Illinois Height Modernization](http://www.isgs.illinois.edu/illinois-height-modernization-lidar-derivatives) project? Apparently, they have LiDAR data including DEMs with resolution <1 meter for many counties. See [here](http://clearinghouse.isgs.illinois.edu/data/elevation/illinois-height-modernization-ilhmp-lidar-data).

Comment: @AndreSilva Your comments would make a nice answer;)

Answer (score 1):

> What recourse do I have in this situation?

Acquire/integrate data with finer resolution.

> Can the 10m DEM be re-sampled perhaps to more accurately reflect the actual landscape?

No, it can't. At least without inputting additional data.

> Should field surveys be employed in addition to re-sampling?

It is an alternative.

---

Alternatively, are you aware of the [Illinois Height Modernization](http://www.isgs.illinois.edu/illinois-height-modernization-lidar-derivatives) project? Apparently, they have LiDAR data including DEMs with resolution <1 meter for many counties. See [here](http://clearinghouse.isgs.illinois.edu/data/elevation/illinois-height-modernization-ilhmp-lidar-data).